# React native: Warning for Shallow renderer

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am using JEST framework for unit testing. I am using Shallow from enzyme for DOM testing. I am getting the following warning after running jest command.

PASS **tests**/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js

● Console
    console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:36
      Warning: Shallow renderer has been moved to react-test-renderer/shallow. Update references to remove this warning.

My test is

```js
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import CheckboxWithLabel from '../app/Component8/CheckboxWithLabel';

test('CheckboxWithLabel changes the text after click', () => {
  // Render a checkbox with label in the document
  const checkbox = shallow(
    <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" />
  );
    
  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('Off');

  checkbox.find('input').simulate('change');

  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('On');
});
```

My package.json

```css
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "linkify-it": "^2.0.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.43.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "~15.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: check this [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/875) in enzyme node module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Enzyme docs:

If you are using React >=15.5, in addition to enzyme, you will have to ensure that you also have the following npm modules installed if they were not already:

`npm i --save-dev react-test-renderer react-dom`